# How to paste plain text in TinyMCE without extra newlines?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am having a problem in TinyMCE when I use `paste_as_text: true` in conjunction with `forced_root_block: false`. Pasting already plain-text in works fine, but pasting from Word adds extra `<br>` tags between every newline. It's not like I can simply parse these out, because that breaks correct double-newlines from plain text.

I have noticed that pasting with ctrl-shift-v fixes this issue, and would love to make that the default pasting method, but can't find how.

I'm currently trying to write a parser to use in `paste_preprocess`, but since it's possible to do in other ways, I figure there must be a better solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Never found a solution; I ended up writing an overly-complicated `paste_preprocess`.

Comment: what happens when you add option `paste_word_valid_elements: ""`

Answer (score 1):

Pasting from Microsoft Word is broken in must copy and paste/Cliboard APIs. you will need to modify [Newline.js](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/src/plugins/paste/src/main/js/core/Newlines.js) or [Clipboard.js](http://%20https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/src/plugins/paste/src/main/js/core/Clipboard.js) manually.

For example, replace [line 63 in Newline.js](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/src/plugins/paste/src/main/js/core/Newlines.js#L63):

```
return p.split(/\n/).join('<br />');
```

with:

```
return p.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>');
```

If you can open an issue on [the plugin page](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce), I will create a proper pull request.

Comment: This appears to help only with the Windows carriage-return character.